# Asymptotic analysis using the master theorem on a fictitious mergesort example

Tags: algorithm, big-o, mergesort, asymptotic-complexity, master-theorem

Suppose we have a fictitious merge sort where the merge operation costs `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`. Then from the master theorem, we have:

```
T(n) <= aT(n/b) + O(n^d)
T(n) <= 2T(n/2) + O(n^2)
```

Since `a < b^d`, we find that:

```
T(n) = O(n^d)
T(n) = O(n^2)
```

However, intuitively, it also makes sense that the big O would be `T(n) = O(n^2 logn)` since each recursion will perform a quadratic (`n^2`) search through the numbers. For example, in the linear search case, merge sort is `O(n logn)`. Does anyone know why the bound is not `O(n^2 logn)`? Could it be something to do with the fact that the search is being halved on each recursion?

Answer (score 0):

We can think of the time taken for normal merge sort as follows (we merge 2 lists of size `n/2`, we merge 4 lists of size `n/4`, we merge 8 lists of size `n/8`, etc):

`2(n/2) + 4(n/4) + 8(n/8) + 16(n/16) + ... + n(1)`

which simplifies to:

`n + n + n + ... + n = O(nlogn)`

For your new merge sort we have instead:

`2(n/2)^2 + 4(n/4)^2 + 8(n/8)^2 + 16(n/16)^2 + ... + n(1)^2`

which simplifies to:

`n^2/2 + n^2/4 + n^2/8 + n^2/16 + ...`

which then becomes:

`n^2(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...) = O(n^2)`

I hope this appeals to your intuition.

Comment: but this doesn't explain why the case for b = 2, d = 1 is O(n log n)

Comment: @willywonkadailyblah: My answer doesn't attempt to explain the Master Theorem. It simply tries to explain the time complexities of the two variants of merge sort in an intuitive manner to answer the original question of "Why `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n^2 logn)`?"